# How to avoid using date function on column for performance gain via indexing

Tags: sql, function, date, select, db2

In below mentioned query how can i avoid using date function on column. due to use of date function the index on col1 is not getting invoked leading to performance issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT *            
FROM table1 
WHERE  date(a.col1)< CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS          
WITH UR  ;
```

Comment: You are selecting all columns, so depending on the size of your table, and how many rows satisfy your predicate, it may be more efficient to full scan than to do index scans and many row lookups.

Comment: Why do you use `date(a.col1)` ? What's the data type of `col1`?

Comment: a.col1 is of data type Timestamp. The function date(a.col1) is used to convert the value to type date so that all values for that date is considered for evaluation. Also the actual query is not select * its select col2.

Answer (score 3):

What format is col1?

Bascially, instead of converting col1, convert the date..

Assuming for instance a numeric value YYYYMMDD...

```
SELECT *            
FROM table1 
WHERE  a.col1 < year(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS) * 10000
                 + month(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS) * 100
                 + day(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS)
WITH UR  ;
```

The expression will only be calculated once.

But you have to have a comparable format, YYYYMMDD...MMDDYYYY would not work correctly.

Another option is to create a CALENDAR table.  It's a better option IMO, as it's useful for lots of things.  One column of it would match the format of col1, another would have an actual date type.

```
SELECT *            
FROM table1 a
      join calendar_tbl c
            on a.col1 = c.MMMDDYY 
WHERE  
   c.calDate < CURRENT DATE - 1 days
WITH UR  ;
```

Lots of articles about using calendar tables on the net; along with code to create them.

**Edit**
Ok, so with the additional information that col1 is a timestamp...the first solution is the best idea.  It's even easier with timestamps.  If you pass just a date to the `TIMESTAMP()` function, it returns a timestamp with the date you pass and a time of 00.00.00.

```
SELECT *            
FROM table1 
WHERE  a.col1 < timestamp(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS)
WITH UR  ;
```

Comment: I am a _HUGE_ proponent of calendar tables. Whenever I inherit a new database, it's one of the first things I'll add when I have to modify something involving dates.

Comment: Calendar tables are, hands down, the most useful dimension/aggregating tables.  It makes all your queries about time-based information SARGable, and likely to use indices (not guaranteed, though).

Comment: a.col1 is of data type Timestamp. The function date(a.col1) is used to convert the value to type date so that all values for that date is considered for evaluation. Also the actual query is not select * its select col2. –. The first solution you have provided will not work as we need all the values from the date calculated. The second solution to use calendar tables is not working, not sure why. I am using DB2 database is this feature supported in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is getting all dates of `col1` (without the timestamp) before the current time yesterday.  Well, I think this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE a.col1 <= date(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS) ;
```

This should be able to take advantage of an index on `col1`, if an index is appropriate for the query.  It is quite possible, though, that the volume of data is so large that an index would not be used in any case.

Comment: Depending on the exact version of DB2 (I think this applies to LUW too, although can't check that at the moment), the type of `col1` may generate syntax errors.  `CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS` should generate a date type too, since `CURRENT DATE` returns a date type (so wrapping it in the function I don't believe has any effect).  Also, you made the range `<=` instead of just `<`, which is very different (and since dates/time/timestamps are positive, contiguous-range types, probably will cause incorrect behavior)

Comment: This solution gives data type incompatibility error. Please propose an alternate.